# Add CustomComponent in Window?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin

I created a CustomComponent and I wanna add this CustomComponent in a WindowTemplate created. I solved create a WindowTemplate for all Window of my project, but I still can not add CustomComponent in template window.

I'm trying this.

```
/** WindowTemplate for all Window configs app */
public class WindowTemplate extends Window{ 
    public WindowTemplate(String title, CustomComponent cc){
    super(title);       
    setSizeUndefined();
    setModal(true);
    setClosable(false);
    setDraggable(false);
    setResizable(false);        
    setIcon(new ThemeResource("../icons/ibg_icon.png"));
    HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    hLayout.addComponent(cc);
    setContent(hLayout);
    center();
}
}


/** my customcomponent */
public class CadCur extends CustomComponent {
    private AbsoluteLayout mainLayout;  
    private TextField email;

public CadCur() {
    buildMainLayout();
    setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
}

@AutoGenerated
private AbsoluteLayout buildMainLayout() {      
    mainLayout = new AbsoluteLayout();
    mainLayout.setImmediate(false);
    mainLayout.setWidth("100%");
    mainLayout.setHeight("100%");

    // top-level component properties
    setWidth("100.0%");
    setHeight("100.0%");

    // email
    email = new TextField();
    email.setCaption("Email");
    email.setImmediate(false);
    email.setWidth("50.0%");
    email.setHeight("-1px");
    email.setRequired(true);
    mainLayout.addComponent(email, "top:96.0px;left:43.0px;");

    return mainLayout;
}
```

}

```
/** a UI class */
public class PrincipalUI extends UI{
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {            
        getCurrent().addWindow(new WindowTemplate("MyWindow", new CadCur());
}
}
```

How to do this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you aren't seeing any results is because all of your components have relative sizes and none of them has anything to depend on. So eventually everything is squished to one point.

One of the solutions may be setting the size of hLayout to full so that it will occupy all the space in the window and then defining the size of your window.

```
public WindowTemplate(String title, CustomComponent cc) {
    super(title);       
    setWidth("200px");
    setHeight("200px");

    // ...

    HorizontalLayout hLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    hLayout.setSizeFull();

    // ...
```